# SVN update returns nothing, while it should

Tags: svn, repository, svn-checkout

First some background information;

- I've set up my SVN repository on my local server at home using VisualSVN Server.
- Using SSH on (or via php/shell script), i am able to check out a folder from this repository to the webserver, all goes well.
- Also updates and other svn commands execute normaly and return their messages.

Now comes the problem, and I'm struggling with this for a few days now.

Before I execute the checkout command *svn co http://server_home/folder*, I want to make sure no conflicts are going to happen, so I execute *svn status [folder_on_webserver]*.

But this doesn't return the result as expected, it returns nothing. When I execute * svn status --show-updates [folder_on_webserver]* it returns the following:

```
       *            newfolder
       *       13   anotherfolder
       *       13   yetanotherfolder
       *       13   .
Status against revision:     16
```

As you can see it misses the svn codes (A,U,D).

Does somebody knows why the *svn update* command and the svn codes doesnt work?

Answer (score 2):

`svn status` will not work before `svn co`. You need to have your repository checked out before you can check the status. Use `svn up` to update.